# Phone Number Extracting using RegEx And HtmlAgilityPack In Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, html-agility-pack

i've written this whole code to extract cell numbers from a website
but the thing is it is extracting numbers perfectly but very slowly it's also hanging my Form while Extracting, pleaase help me to make it run faster.

and run more efficiently.

```
Imports HtmlAgilityPack
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Public Class Extractor

Shared doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()

Public Shared Function ScrapLinks(TextBox1 As TextBox, ListBox1 As ListBox, lbllinks As Label)
    Dim hw As New HtmlWeb()
    Try
        doc = hw.Load(TextBox1.Text)
        doc.LoadHtml(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='ad_list']").InnerHtml())

        For Each link As HtmlNode In doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")

            Dim hrefValue As String = link.GetAttributeValue("href", String.Empty)

            If hrefValue.Contains("/detail/") Then
                If Not ListBox1.Items.Contains(hrefValue) Then
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(hrefValue)
                End If
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error " + ex.Message)

    End Try
    Return Nothing

End Function

Public Shared Function Scrapnums(lstbox As ListBox,lstnum As ListBox)
    Try

        Dim hw As New HtmlWeb()
        doc = hw.Load(lstbox.SelectedItem)

        Dim data = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@class='det_ad f_left']").InnerText

        Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(data, "(\+92|0092)-?\d{3}-?\d{7}|\d{11}|\d{4}-\d{7}")


        If Not lstnum.Items.Contains(m.Value) Then

            lstnum.Items.Add(m.Value)

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception


    End Try
    Return Nothing

End Function

End Class
```

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've asked the question on codereview Thanks for reference!

Comment: I managed to create a possible regex for the question you've just deleted.

Comment: @pushpraj sorry but i was feeling bad because of some down grades on my Question.

Comment: @pushpraj Kindly post your regex over here! please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a regex to parse the phone numbers

**Regex**

```
((?(?=\+92|0092)(?:\+|00)92\d?(?:-\d{3}-?\d{7}|-?\d{9}|\d{10})|(?:\d{11}|\d{3}\s\d{3}\s\d{5,6}|\d{4}-\d{7})))
```

**Sample numbers**

```
+92-3113143446
+923-113143446
032 124 26003
923 072 776037
03154031162
+923218923116
0307-2796038
+92-343-2842120
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  1. [0-14]  `+92-3113143446`
- MATCH 2

  1. [15-29] `+923-113143446`
- MATCH 3

  1. [30-43] `032 124 26003`
- MATCH 4

  1. [44-58] `923 072 776037`
- MATCH 5

  1. [59-70] `03154031162`
- MATCH 6

  1. [71-84] `+923218923116`
- MATCH 7

  1. [85-97] `0307-2796038`
- MATCH 8

  1. [98-113]    `+92-343-2842120`

**Demo**

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rW8vR6/1)**

above regex is based on assumptions, it may match more patterns then listed above. so it may need to be refined as needed.

Comment: I am glad it helped you. Secondly do not worry about down-votes, wait for some time to see if there is an answer on the way. You can choose to delete the question any time, and you'll get back your lost reputation. last but not the least, happy coding :)